# Watson Discovery - Delete documents

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

Is there any possibility to delete documents from a watson discovery collection by date.

Something I would do in a SQL database like this:

```
DELETE FROM collection_name 
WHERE publication_date < 2018-01-01;
```

I know, I can delete single documents by name and I could query the documents with a publication_date filer and after querying I could iterate over the document names and delete every single document but this seems a rather annoying approach for a quite simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user3609367 there is no way to delete multiple documents with a single API call.  The approach you have mentioned in your post is the best way to do what you are asking.

Comment: I also experienced that deleting many documents from a collection iteratively is very slow (probably due to the fact that I am using the free "lite"-plan).